# mounting remote drive works only when executed in line by line not from a script

Tags: mount, script, automount, sshfs

I am trying to mount network data.  This works if I enter the following commands into the shell:

```
cd ~
sshfs user@ssh.company.com:/ /home/userName/remoteWork
```

If I however, put those commands in a script and try to run it, it does not work.  I am prompted for my password, it seems to accept it, but the mount doesn't happen.  Why wouldn't the commands work from a script?  Must I add commands?

Comment: Anything in the logs?

Comment: Have to ask - how are you determining the mount didn't happen? The command operates silently so personally I use df -h afterwords to verify it.

Comment: You tagged this as "automount" - whose userid is running the script you mention?

Comment: I'm not sure where the logs are but perhaps the df -h was the command for the logs, and after I changed permissions to 755 it seems to work (as seen in the logs and testing), even though I could have sworn I had made it executable.  Thanks for the help guys, I know that was a silly mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first command to cd ~ is not required but that's not a problem.

I just tried exactly the same commands in a shell script (bash) and it worked.  It may be obvious, but the path /home/userName/remoteWork must already exist and have perms that allow you to use it - say your userid with 755 perms.